# How do I show all the buttons text with normal font on UIAlertView in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uialertview

In my iOSproject I have an `UIAlertView` with 3 buttons on it , but the last button text is defaulted to bold font like this...  , how can I set the font style of third button text to normal ? 
[image]

following is the code used to create that alert view

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"testTestTest" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"first",@"second",@"third" ,nil];
    [alert show];
```

Comment: Please put code of your alertView may be your "third" is tile of cancel button so you need to change it as normal other button title :)

Comment: @iPatel  even i had the same guess,,but even after changing that to normal button it didn't work out

Comment: Is there a way to make the first and second button have bold text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent some time on this and went to dig along subview structure of present view controller when UIAlertView is presented. I am able to show normal font to all button text.

I have created a subclass of UIAlertView :

Header File :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MLKLoadingAlertView : UIAlertView

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;

@end
```

Implementation File :

```
#import "MLKLoadingAlertView.h"

#define ACTIVITY_INDICATOR_CENTER   CGPointMake(130, 90)

@implementation MLKLoadingAlertView

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    if ( self = [super init] )
    {
        self.title = title;
        self.message = @"\n\n";
        [self addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
        [self addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
        [self addButtonWithTitle:@"Sure"];

        [self setDelegate:self];
    }

    return self;
}

// You can Customise this based on your requirement by adding subviews.
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    NSArray *subviews = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController.view.subviews;

    if( subviews.count > 1 )
    {
        // iOS while presenting an alertview uses a presening view controller. That controller's view has several subviews. I have picked one
        // subview from it which has frame similar to the alertview frame.
        UIView *presentedView = [subviews objectAtIndex:1];

        for( UIView *view in presentedView.subviews )
        {
            for( UIView *subView in view.subviews )
            {
                if( [subView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]] )
                {
                    NSInteger numberOfButtons = [(UITableView *)subView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
                    UITableViewCell *buttonCell = [(UITableView *)subView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:numberOfButtons-1 inSection:0]];


                    for( UIView *cellSubView in buttonCell.contentView.subviews )
                    {
                        if( [cellSubView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] )
                        {
                            [(UILabel *)cellSubView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        UIActivityIndicatorView *customActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [customActivityIndicator startAnimating];
        customActivityIndicator.center = ACTIVITY_INDICATOR_CENTER;

        [presentedView addSubview:customActivityIndicator];
    }
}
```

I have created instance of this MLKLoadingAlertView in my View Controller like this :

```
    MLKLoadingAlertView *loadingAlertView = [[MLKLoadingAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:TITLE];
    [loadingAlertView show];
```

This will show following output :

[image]

Using this approach we can achieve two things :

1. We can add subviews to UIAlertView in iOS 7
2. We can change font of button text in iOS 7

**Note** : This approach may only work with iOS 7.

Comment: Your third button is not Bold.

Comment: @MikeMilla, third button looks similar to first two buttons. What difference you found there? Why did you down voted my answer?

Comment: @MikeMilla, please read the question carefully before down voting answers. He asked all his buttons with normal font (without bold). I gave response as per his question.

Answer (score 1):

cancelButtonTitle
The title of the cancel button as empty it will show like below image

```
  UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!" 
                                                      message:@"This is your first UIAlertview message." 
                                                     delegate:self 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@" "
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Button 1",@"Button 2", @"Button 3", nil];



    [message show];
```

[image]

Comment: But its adding an extra blank cancel button at the end

Comment: because the cancel button always highlighted in alertview

Answer (score 0):

undocumented subview structure of a standard UI control

```
@interface:UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>

 - (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
       for(UIView *view in alertView.subviews)
        if(([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) && (view.tag ==3)){
            UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)view;
            [myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0]];

        }
}
```

or

[how-to-change-uialertview-fontcolors](http://blog.pixatra.com/2012/08/how-to-change-uialertview-fontcolors.html)

```
-(void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)a;ertView{
UILabel *title = [alertView valurForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18];
[title setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor];

UILabel *body = [alertView valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
body.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
[body setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous. It could crash or simply fail in some iOS update.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks this is i know if you have best approach please post it helpful

Comment: Please, whenever you post code that digs into the private, undocumented subview structure of a standard UI control, you should point it out in the answer. Not everyone seeing your answer would know this.

Comment: for calling delegate methods he should set delegate:self in place of delegate:Nil

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting solution or facing problem then try to custom alert view. that are very easy to use blow i apply link

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pxalertview

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sialertview