# iOS: How to set custom font to alert action (alert button) ?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, custom-font, uialertaction

I am able to set custom font for title and message of the alert but i am not able to set custom font for alert action / button. Is there a way to do so? Please help! Many thanks!!

Comment: Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423681/how-do-i-show-all-the-buttons-text-with-normal-font-on-uialertview-in-ios

Comment: This is outdated. UIAlertView has deprecated. Now iOS is having UIAlertController. I am asking question the UIAlertAction. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744237/how-to-edit-uialertaction-text-font-size-and-color

Comment: you might be able to update via KVC as above link and also in following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color . Best of luck!

Comment: There is no effecient way to do accomplish your task. Check my ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214154/how-to-edit-uialertaction-button-font-size/45214307#45214307

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ, yes i've found answer from other link about the same way doing it by KVC. It works. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @luckyShubhra i got problem solved. thanks!

Comment: The customization for `UIAlertAction` uses private apis that might get your app rejected in publishing in the App Store.

Comment: Consider @nayem advise.Using private apis might get your app rejected in publishing.

Comment: I will take that under consideration. Thanks for good advice! @nayem

Comment: Thank you too @luckyShubhra

Comment: Welcome man  :) ....